# How to calculate the derived subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let's say I want to calculate the derived subgroup of the infinite dihedral group $D_{\infty}$ given by the presentation

$$\langle x,a | x^2 = e, \ xax=a^{-1}\rangle$$

The derived series is the subgroup generated by commutators:

$$D(D_{\infty}) = \{ghg^{-1}h^{-1}|g,h\in D_{\infty}\} $$

If I want to calculate this subgroup is it sufficient to calculate the commutators for the generators $x,a$? That is

$$xax^{-1}a^{-1}  $$
$$axa^{-1}x^{-1}$$

which give the elements $a^2,a^{-2}$ (as far as my calculations are correct)

Comment: I don't think your generators are correct. For example $xax=x^{-1},$ means that $x^2ax=e,$ but then $ax=e,$ so $x=a^{-1}.$ Did you mean $xax^{-1}=a^{-1}$ ?

Comment: @Justin: I was sure about the typo, so I just fixed it.

Comment: In this example $[G,G]$ is indeed generated by $a^2$, since $G/\langle a^2 \rangle$ is abelian of order $4$, but it is not true in general that $[G,G]$ is generated by the commutators of the group generators. For example in a nonabelian free group of finite rank $[G,G]$ is not even finitely generated.

Comment: @DerekHolt So how would I calculate it?

Comment: You have calculated it,

Comment: If this isn't true in general then how should I know if my answer is correct? Do you have a general strategy?

Comment: I explained in my first comment why your answer is correct.

Comment: You said, I quote "but it is not true in general that $[G,G]$  is generated by the commutators of the group generators". So if you didn't tell me that *in this particular case* the derived subgroup is generated by the commutators of the group commutators I wouldn't have known that this is correct. So I'm asking again what the general strategy is to determine the derived subgroup. If there is none I'm also fine with that.